# Nested class & readonly properties

Tags: vb.net, properties, readonly

Outside the class I'd like to be able to access CCTV.Camera.Brightness property as ReadOnly, but methods within the CCTV class should be able to modify the Brightness property.  Please can you advise on how to achieve this?

I think I need to add an Interface that exposes some properties and hides others, but I'm not sure of the implementation. [Note the constructor and main sub are obviously contrived for this example and testing].

```
Public Class CCTV

   Public Class Camera
       Public Property Name as String
       Public Property Brightness as Integer
   End Class

   Dim cameras as New Dictionary(Of String, Camera)
   Public Sub New()
      Dim cam As New Camera
      cam.Name = "driveway"
      cam.Brightness = 5
      cameras.Add(cam.Name, cam)
   End Sub

   Public Sub ChangeBrightness(value as Integer)
      cameras("driveway").Brightness = value
   End Sub

End Class

Sub main()
  Dim MyCCTV = new CCTV
  MyCCTV.ChangeBrightness(10)
  if MyCCTV("driveway").Brightness = 10 then Console.Write("Brightness is 10")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get getter and the setter of a property can have different accessibility modifiers.  In this case you want Brightness to be readable by everybody but only the code you trust should be able to write it.  You do so like this:

```
Public Class Camera
    Private _brightness As Integer

    Public Property Brightness As Integer
        Get
            Return _brightness
        End Get
        Friend Set(value As Integer)
            _brightness = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '' etc...
End Class
```

Note the added `Friend` keyword, it limits access to the code in the same project that Camera class is a part of.  It can also be `Private` or `Protected` if you want to limit access to only code inside the Camera class or its derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

no interface is need in this case.You simply have to create your property as readonly.when you set the property as readonly assume that the value will stored within a private variable and at that point should be better pass it or to a method or to the subnew using overloads methods let me show you an example:

```
Public Class CCTV

Public Class Camera
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _Brightness As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Brightness() As String
        Get
            Return _Brightness
        End Get

    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Defautl sub new method
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Sub New()

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' second overload
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cameraName"></param>
    ''' <param name="brightness"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Sub New(ByVal cameraName As String, ByVal brightness As Integer)
        Me.Name = cameraName
        Me._Brightness = brightness
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Change brigthness
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub setUpCameraBrightness(ByVal value As Integer)
        'take care to use private varibale so it will reflcet changes into propetry readonly
        Me._Brightness = value
    End Sub
End Class

Dim cameras As New Dictionary(Of String, Camera)
Public Sub New()
    'two differnet approach 
    'first overaload:
    Dim cam As New Camera()
    cam.Name = "yourcamname"
    cam.setUpCameraBrightness(10)
    cameras.Add(cam.Name, cam)



    ''second approch declarative value:
    Dim cam2 As New Camera("yourcamname", 10)
    cameras.Add(cam2.Name, cam2)

End Sub

Public Sub ChangeBrightness(value As Integer)
    cameras("driveway").setUpCameraBrightness(100)
End Sub

End Class

Sub main()
    Dim MyCCTV = New CCTV
    MyCCTV.ChangeBrightness(10)
    If MyCCTV("driveway").Brightness = 10 Then Console.Write("Brightness is 10")
End Sub
```